# Why don't two sequential coroutines (async functions) execute in parallel?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, tornado

So, I'm just trying to wrap my head around async programming (in particular the Tornado framework), and thought I'd start with the basics: calling "awaiting" on two coroutines:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, url, RequestHandler
from tornado.gen import sleep

class TestHandler(RequestHandler):    
    async def get(self):
        f1 = await self.test("f1")
        f2 = await self.test("f2")
        self.write(f1 + " " + f2)

    async def test(self, msg):
        for i in range(5):
            print(i)
            await sleep(1) # this is tornado's async sleep
        return msg

app = Application([url(r'/', TestHandler)], debug=True)
app.listen(8080)
ioloop = IOLoop.current()
ioloop.start()
```

The issue, however, is that when I hit `localhost:8080` in my browser, and stare at my python console, I don't see two interwoven sequences of `0 1 2 3 4`, but two sequential sequences...

I've read the Tornado [FAQ](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=sleep#why-isn-t-this-example-with-time-sleep-running-in-parallel) over-and-over again and can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This runs `f1`, waits for it to finish, then runs `f2`:

```
    f1 = await self.test("f1")
    f2 = await self.test("f2")
```

To run things in parallel, you can't `await` the first one before starting the second. The simplest way to do this is to do them both in one `await`:

```
f1, f2 = await tornado.gen.multi(self.test("f1"), self.test("f2"))
```

Or in advanced cases, you can start `f1` without waiting for it then come back to wait for it later:

```
f1_future = tornado.gen.convert_yielded(self.test("f1"))
f2_future = tornado.gen.convert_yielded(self.test("f2"))
f1 = await f1_future
f2 = await f2_future
```

Comment: The second code block (with the awaited futures) doesn't run in parallel... Am I misunderstanding you and it shouldn't be expected to?

Comment: Ah, you're right. This pattern worked with `@gen.coroutine` but `async def` functions don't start until something `awaits` them.

Comment: would you mind explaining best practices? It would seem that Tornado and `asyncio` (in particular `async`/`await`) don't really play well together. How should we go about writing/decorating async code (given we want to use Tornado)?

Comment: async/await have some limitations, but I think they're still worth using. They're new, though, and so people are still figuring out how they interact with other features. If you don't want to break new ground you can stick with `@gen.coroutine` and `yield`.

Comment: this still makes me wonder how we're supposed to cleanly integrate the two modules?

Comment: Using `await` on its own or with `gen.multi` works in most cases. Explicitly calling `convert_yielded` is a last resort but helps in some more complicated cases. If there are particular cases you can't come up with a clean solution to, post a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Parallelism - [official example](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html?highlight=await#parallelism)

The `multi` function accepts lists and dicts whose values are `Futures`, and waits for all of those `Futures` in parallel:

```py
from tornado.gen import multi

async def parallel_fetch(url1, url2):
    resp1, resp2 = await multi([http_client.fetch(url1),
                                http_client.fetch(url2)])

async def parallel_fetch_many(urls):
    responses = await multi ([http_client.fetch(url) for url in urls])
    # responses is a list of HTTPResponses in the same order

async def parallel_fetch_dict(urls):
    responses = await multi({url: http_client.fetch(url)
                             for url in urls})
    # responses is a dict {url: HTTPResponse}
```